# Como evitar errores al acceder a selectores con Javascript luego de ser compilado con laravel mix

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Al separar en varios archivos `.js` en resources y después generando el bundle con mix, estoy usando jquery, **¿cómo puedo hacer para comprobar si existen ciertos selectores?** Lo he intentado comprobando por el path y luego ejecutando las funciones necesarias para esa vista, pero me gustaría hacerlo de otra manera.

Gracias.

```js
if (window.location.pathname.includes("/students")) {
// accedo a selectores que se que existen en esa vista
}
```

Comment: por lo general lo que se hace como buena practica es generar un script por cada vista, en un script global dejas tus funciones globales como por ejemplo un spinner loading que sabes que usaras en toda tu app, luego como usas un script en cada vista lo que haces es incluirla mediante un stack dejandola de modo defer en todo el documento

Comment: puedes mostrar el tipo de error que intentas evitar? En general jQuery te permite usar su wrapper indistintamente de si el elemento existe

Comment: TypeError por ejemplo al acceder a $(selector).val() que no está presente en todas las vistas. O tengo que validar nomas antes de acceder a los mismos?

Comment: en webpack.mix.js agrego mix.js("resources/js/script.js", "public/js") por cada script y de ahí lo cargo en la vista decís?